# Diffrence between getpriority() and sched_priority

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm new to kernel and I would like to know what is the difference between these functions. Do both return the same priority of the process?

Answer (score 0):

No,

`getpriority()` returns the `nice` value of the process or thread, which is typically a value between `-19` and `20`, with `-19` being the highest priority. type `man nice` for more information. If you look at `top` the `NI` column is the nice value.

`sched_priority` is the the `PR` column in `top`, the values possible are dependant on the scheduler you're using, for the extreme threads there is the real time scheduler, which means you can set processes to `-99` priority.

The way `nice` and `priority` interact depends on the scheduler, for all the permutations you should read this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html